# Show folders in NSPopUpButton

Tags: objective-c, macos, directory, nspopupbutton

I want to show folders with icons in my NSPopUpButton. It is common for popups that used for selecting path for file. I'm new user and i can't post images. U can see that for example in U Torrent->preferences->directories

Please provide detailed answer because I'm completely new at that.

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each `NSMenuItem` in your menu, you need to set the appropriate image, calling [`setImage:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/classes/nsmenuitem_class/reference/reference.html)

In short, you need to prepare your menu item, attach it to a menu, and attach the latter to your popup button, like so:

```
NSPopUpButton *yourButton = [[NSPopUpButton alloc] init];
NSMenu *yourMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];

NSMenuItem *menuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"some label" action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
NSImage *iconImage = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:@"yourFilePath"];
[iconImage setSize:NSMakeSize(16,16)];

[menuItem setImage:iconImage];
[yourMenu insertItem:menuItem atIndex:0];
[yourButton setMenu:yourMenu];
```

Note the use of [`iconForFile:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in `NSWorkspace`, which allows you to show the same icon used in the Finder.

For more examples, you can have a look at this sample code by Apple: [ButtonMadness](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ButtonMadness/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004430)